# Why Gigabit Ethernet Direct Connect is not default at Macs?

Tags: macos, network, performance, ethernet

Trying to connect two Macintoshs with a Ethernet cable (capable of Gigabit speed, of course) will not automatically set a gigabit connection. Instead of this, a 100MB connection is established. Does anybody knows why? After a thousand searchs at google, and trying with a bunch of machines, I still on limbo.  Both ports are capable and set to Gigabit speed, imho. Thanks for any advice, answering or any way I should/could improve this question.

Both Macs tested are:
Both iMac (late 2011+), iMac + MacPro (Late 2009+)
All machines running Yosemite full updated.

Comment: Have you tried a different cable?

Comment: Suggest you confirm that both Macs are set to automatically configure the ethernet port – see System Preferences -> Network -> Select your ethernet port in list of interfaces -> Select 'advanced' -> select the 'hardware' tab.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem ? I'm having the same issue here.

Answer (score 1):

Gigabit Ethernet is new technology in wired networking so if you're using a crossover cable, it will only work up to 100Mbps. Use a straight cable instead.

In [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_crossover_cable):

> An Ethernet crossover cable is a type of Ethernet cable used to
>   connect computing devices together directly. It is most often used to
>   connect two devices of the same type: e.g. two computers (via network
>   interface controller) or two switches to each other. By contrast,
>   patch cables or straight through cables are used to connect devices of
>   different types, such as a computer to a network switch or hub.
>
> **Many devices today support Auto MDI-X capability, wherein a patch**
>   **cable can be used in place of a crossover cable**, or vice versa, and
>   the receive and transmit signals are reconfigured automatically to
>   yield the expected result.

To make things easier to understand, network interface cards (NICs) back then were "dumb" so they still need separate lines for receive and transmit signals. Now, NICs can identify both in one line.

Comment: This cross over issue is gone long years ago. I guess this is not the answer for what I am asking about.

Comment: Yes, the issue with crossover cables between 2 computers have been resolved long ago, so why do you still use it? The resolution they did is to allow straight cables to any 2 devices (computer-computer, computer-hub, hub-hub, etc.) universally. The cables didn't change, the NICs did. If that doesn't satisfy you, have you checked your cables if they have proper contacts?